# MorphToMany relation empty in `created` Model Observer

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-tags

I am using Laravel Nova and have an `Entry` model that uses [spatie/nova-tags-field](https://github.com/spatie/nova-tags-field). (*Under the hood this package uses a `morphToMany` relation between models and tags via a trait*)

I attached a model observer on the `created` event.

I want to access the entry's tags in the observer like this:

```
public function created(Entry $entry)
{
    $tags = $entry->tags;
}
```

But `$tags` is always an empty array `[]`, yet I can access the models tags later (not in the observer, but anywhere else) using Entry::find($id)->tags. My guess is that the morphToMany pivot table entry for the attached tags is being created after the observer fires?

Thank for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the [`attachTags`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-tags/blob/491c209449ed792574349220bb6528eba6b18c32/src/HasTags.php#L145) method in your `Entry` and fire a custom event when `$this->wasRecentlyCreated` is `true`.

Also you could listen to the `created` event (or any other) of [your own tag model](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-tags/v2/advanced-usage/using-your-own-tag-model/).
In combination with `$touches` something close to your desired behaviour may be possible. But obviously the `created` event of your `Entry` will always be fired before any tags are attached.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried overwriting the `attachTags` method, but not being aware of `$this->wasRecentlyCreated` I didnt know how to fire only when a model is created. I will look into it and provide feedback, thanks again!

Comment: `$this->wasRecentlyCreated` is `true` when the model was created in the current request. So unless you attach tags in multiple places this should probably work.